# Is public transport in Naha, Okinawa good enough for day trips?

Tags: public-transport, japan, day-trips, okinawa

I am planning on staying 3 nights in Naha and was hoping to get to see a lot of the island and possibly other islands on day trips.

Is the public transport frequent and accessible enough to venture outside of Naha and return the hotel on the same day, or should I plan on booking a hotel outside of Naha? I don't have any specific attractions at this stage, but would like to visit some beaches and other islands.

Comment: I'd recommend rewording to be specific about what you mean by "good enough".  It means something different to different people. Is it just meaning "it's possible" or "easy" or "readily accessible" for example?

Comment: Hopefully that edit is good enough. This is just like COSC all over again... :D

Comment: Haha, brilliant :)  Lab4 memories? ;)

Comment: Yeah at least one of those labs.

Comment: What's a COSC? What's a Lab4?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is. If you go to [this online-bus map](http://routefinder-okinawa.com/route_search?Lang=en), you will see that there are tons of stations all over the island. Zoom out of the google maps and check the tickbox "bus stops" in the orange field above it. I am sure you will find one near where you want to go. One of the [longest routes](http://routefinder-okinawa.com/result?FromCode=730476&FromAddr=&FromPoint=&ToCode=728520&ToAddr=&ToPoint=&Date=09/30/2013&Time=17:09&DepOrArr=departure&Order=1&Speed=2&Lang=en) from downtown Naha will take you only 3.5 hours, provided you take the highway bus as suggested by the route finder.

Otherwise, there are also ferries, but I would assume that they are much slower than the bus unless you want to go to another island.

There is also a small train (1 line only) from the Naha Airport to downtown Naha.

Taxis are always a (not so cheap) option too, of course.